# How to group records in CoreData by column value?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have the next table in CoreData entity:

```
`title`
`description`
`category`
```

Now I want to group all records by `category`. For example:

```
("A", "B", "Cat")
("C", "D", "Dog")
("E", "F", "Cat")
```

I want to get them in a dictionary like: `[Category: [Items]]`

Where `Category` is struct like (title, description) and `Items` is my above described structure like (title, description, category).

So as a result I want to get dictionary

```
[Category("Cat"): [Items("A", "E")], Category("Dog"): [Items("C")]]
```

How can I do that in Swift?

I've tried to do with distinct but I've got wrong results there.

Comment: Not the "silver bullet" you're looking for, but you could use a sort descriptor to get the results sorted by category and then enumerate that and build the groups yourself.

Comment: You could use `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2919592-init. If you want to display in a `UITableView`, you could use a `NSFetchedResultsController` with the `sectionNameKeyPath` set to your `category`

Comment: Nice @Adrian, I learned something new today. :) .

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your example with limited info re: what your data model looks like, I would take whatever entity array you've got and create a dictionary  using [`Dictionary(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2919592-init), as referenced in my comment.

Assuming an Core Data entity with the attributes you reference, you would create a dictionary as follows:

```
let dictionary = Dictionary(grouping: entityArray) { $0.category }
```

This assumes you've got an array of entities with a `title`, `description`, and `category` properties.

Comment: Where should this code be used? Should I change Codegen of CoreData entity to Manual/None or Category/Extension, create a subclass and put this code there?